# Get latest feed and put on top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can display several feeds from different providers using feedburner like this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bD4vm/3/)

I would like to place the latest feed on top. How would I know which feed is the 'newest'?? And how do I get to place it on top? (I would like to do this with Jquery if that is possible)

Answer (score 1):

Append `&displayDate=true` to the feedburner URLs.

Comment: Thanks, but I know this. The problem is that there are many items on a single day.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery `prepend()` on the parent element. This will allow you to place the new feeds at the top.

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/